# Сomputational aspects of linear algebra over arbitrary fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I would like to find a reference on elementary linear algebra which will pay attention to computational aspects of matrices and determinants, and solving systems of linear equations in arbitrary fields, not only over reals and complex numbers.

Comment: I'd be surprised if such a thing exists. People generally don't study arbitrary fields until long after they've done elementary linear algebra, so there'd be no market for such a treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of books like that:

J.S.Golan "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know"

Friedberg "Linear Algebra"

Hoffman-Kunze "Linear Algebra"

Vinberg "A Course in Algebra"(this is abstract algebra book, but it assumes no knowledge of linear algebra and develops the latter from scratch over arbitrary fields).

All of them work over arbitrary fields. And they are introductory(Golan's book is more advanced, but still can be used as an introduction).

Besides, there is P.Aluffi's book "Algebra: Chapter 0". This is a graduate level abstract algebra introduction, but it has a little to none prerequisites. And it develops linear algebra through module theory defining matrices, determinants, systems of linear equations etc. And all over arbitrary fields.